# Javascript rescaling mobile webpage when setting left of div

Tags: javascript

I have got a mobile website using

```
<meta name = "viewport" content = "width = 320">
<meta content='width = 320; initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0' name='viewport' />
```

to set the width of the website to fit and to disallow people from zooming in.

Now I also have 2 divs of which 1 is visible and the second one should slide in when swiped left with your finger. The javascript I use for this is something like

```
var a = 320;
var speed = 10;
function slide(from, to) {
   if (a > 0) {
      from.style.display = "block";
      to.style.display = "block";
      a = a + speed;
      from.style.left = (a - 320) + "px";
      to.style.left = a + "px";
      setTimeout('slide("' + from + '", "' + to + '");', 10);
   } else {
      a = 0;
      from.style.display = "none";
      to.style.display = "block";
   }
}
```

this does work, but for some devices the first time you run this the scale of the website first gets reset to normal and then back to the set 320px width leaving some other divs on the website invisible for no reason.

Does anyone have any idea of why this happens and how this can be solved.
(the phone I know for sure it does the rescaling thing is a samsung galaxy fame)

Thanks,

Merijn den Houting

Comment: on request I will create an example page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with the jQuery animate function, like this:

> > ### slide div1 in
> >
> > ```
> > $( "#div1" ).animate({
> >     left: 0px;
> > }, 1500 );
> > ```

> > ### slide div2 out
> >
> > ```
> > $( "#div2" ).animate({
> >     left: -320px;
> > }, 1500 );
> > ```

Answer (score 0):

As I can't comment I'll have to answer this. I don't know how far the mobile support is but you might want to take a look at CSS-Animations and simply change the classes. Also you might want to try absolute positioning instead or relative positioning (depends on what you're currently using). Also you should try the visibility: hidden or visible attribute. Maybe the change from block to none breaks something.
Because I don't have a Samsung Galaxy Fame I can't check what's going on even if you post a JSFiddle or something similar.

Comment: I actually am using absolute positioning and I have tried the same code without the display: block; but it is still doing the same thing. I will look into CSS-Animations, thanks.

Comment: Make sure to be careful with browser support, mobile browsers are often outdated.